# get record from multiple tables without foreign key relation django

Tags: django, join, orm

I've two django models

```
class Users(models.Model):
    id=models.ForeignKey(VirtualMachines, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True)

class UsersDomains(models.Model):
    domain_email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    domain=models.CharField(null=True)
```

I want to select records from these tables using inner join. models don't have relation between them so i can't use select_related. My sql query is:

```
SELECT u.*, du.* FROM
users u 
JOIN user_domain du 
ON du.domain_email = u.email
```

without using select_related how do i write django ORM query to same record as my sql query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you say you don't have a relationship between those two models. You *do*: it just uses an char field rather than an ID. That's still a perfectly valid foreign key. You should declare your UserDomain like this:

```
class UsersDomains(models.Model):
    domain_email = models.ForeignKey(Users, to_field='email', null=True)
```

and also add `unique=True` to the Users.domain field, and now Django will automatically do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for pointing this out. I ended up doing the same thing that you mentioned. Its working perfect now.

Comment: after converting the field to ForeignKey im getting this error  '' 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith' ''.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman what if i have a combination of keys as unique , how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help -

http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/

basically it's just using the `queryset.query.join` to add whatever join you want..

Comment: Two models in the example have many2many relation between them. Will this work for me? because i don't have relation between models.